# Optional parameters of cv2.calibrateCamera method

Tags: python, opencv

According to documentation the parameters of caliberateCamera functions are as follows.

```
cv2.calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize[, cameraMatrix[, distCoeffs[, rvecs[, tvecs[, flags[, criteria]]]]]]) → retval, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs
```

From what I understand, apart from objectPoints, imagePoints and imageSize all other parameters are optional (since they are placed within brackets). But when I call the function with only first 3 arguments, it throws error.

```
cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, img_size)
```

It works fine if I run it like following.

```
cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, img_size, None, None)
```

What is happening here.

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob


def caliberate_camera():
    "returns objpoints ans imgpoints"

    nx = 9
    ny = 6
    # prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
    objp = np.zeros((ny*nx,3), np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:nx, 0:ny].T.reshape(-1,2)

    # Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
    objpoints = [] # 3d points in real world space
    imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

    # Make a list of calibration images
    images = glob.glob("camera_cal/calibration*.jpg")

    # Step through the list and search for chessboard corners
    for idx, fname in enumerate(images):
       img = cv2.imread(fname)
       gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

       # Find the chessboard corners
       ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (nx,ny), None)

       # If found, add object points, image points
       if ret == True:
          objpoints.append(objp)
          imgpoints.append(corners)

    img = cv2.imread('camera_cal/calibration11.jpg')
    img_size = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])

    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, img_size, None, None)


caliberate_camera()
```

This function runs without any error. However, if I change the last line of the caliberate_camera() function to this

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, img_size)
```

I get this error:

> File "test.py", line 42, in 
>       caliberate_camera()   File "test.py", line 39, in caliberate_camera
>       ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, img_size) TypeError: Required argument 'cameraMatrix' (pos
>   4) not found

Comment: Please, add enough code to reproduce the problem and the error messages.

Comment: What error did you get with 3 arguments?

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? It appears to me you're referring to documentation for 2.4.x while using 3.x. In 3.x [`cv2.calibrateCamera`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d) takes 5 mandatory arguments.

Comment: @DanMašek You are right. Just tried cv2.__version__ on my python console, it gave 3.4.0. 
I was thinking that "2" in "cv2" means that I am using version 2.x. But it looks like CV2 has further versions, like 2.x and 3.x. Thanks a lot.